# Why is "IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN" used in Instead of Insert trigger?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a trigger on a table of mine.

```
CREATE TRIGGER HIE.AI_IB_Export_Events 
   ON HIE.IB_Export_Events 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
```

and the lines following it are :

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN
```

Isn't this something not required ? How can you get to an insert trigger if a row isn't being inserted?

Why do we perform for such checks on an insert ? I can understand the same for update query where no records match the where condition.

and if such conditions arrive where @@ROWCOUNT = 0 then in which scenarios does this happen ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer if an insert trigger would fire even when 0 rows are inserting, I created a simple table and trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (Id INT PRIMARY KEY)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER Test_Trigger ON Test INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Msg nvarchar(4000);
SELECT @Msg = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @@ROWCOUNT) + N' rows inserted (trigger).';
PRINT @Msg;
END
GO
```

If you then run a void insert statement, you'll still see a message:

```
INSERT INTO Test
SELECT 1 WHERE 0 = 1

>> 0 rows inserted (trigger).
```

Note that this will happen for both `INSTEAD OF INSERT` and `AFTER INSERT` triggers.  This behavior makes sense, since an insert of 0 rows is still an insert operation (albeit a not very exciting one).

Should you check for, and return early, if the number of inserted rows is 0?  I would say it depends on the function of your trigger and expectations about the inserted rows (e.g. will it ever happen, and if so, what's the consequence?).

If your trigger is just performing a mapping of the inserted rows and then performing another insert, the check doesn't really matter.  However, if your trigger is firing off some business logic or doing some complex operation to prepare the inserted rows, then the check could make sense.